# Why does char = char - 32 shows loose conversion error while char -= 32 doesn't?

Tags: java

```
class lower_caseToUpperCase {
public static void main(String[] args)
throws java.io.IOException {
     char ch, ignore;
     int case_change = 0;
     do {
      System.out.print("Enter any number of characters: ");
      ch = (char) System.in.read();
         do {
         ignore = (char) System.in.read();
              }while(ignore != '\n'); 
         if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
           ch -= 32;//shows error if you use ch = ch - 32;
            System.out.println(ch);
               case_change++;
             }
          else if(ch >='A' && ch <='Z') {
             ch += 32;//same as above
               System.out.println(ch);
                 case_change++;
              }
         } while(ch != '.');
       System.out.print("No. of case changes = " + case_change);
    }
   }
```

whenever i use char = char +32 it shows loose conversion error
but when i use char += 32 it runs fine. why is it so?
please help..

Answer (score 2):

It is because `32` is integer, so when you write `char = char + int` you're getting warning

but operator `+=` is special one, in java it is resolves to `char = (char)(char + int)` so you don't see warning because of implicit case

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply that's the reason  i was thinking when i later used (char)(char +32) why the program was running fine. :)